# Using Youtube Player API in windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have embedded youtube player in windows 8 app (html/javascript). I need to interact with player (play/pause etc). I copy/pasted example in Getting started section [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) but onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is not fired. I create local html file for the same code and launched html file in chrome but same results. This code works fine when I use w3schools try it page.
I found better example to interact with youtube player [here](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ytplayer/iframe/index.html). I copied index.js, index.html and index.css locally on desktop. trying to run index.html from desktop doesnt work (basically onYouTubeIframeAPIReady  not fired).

My ultimate goal it to know when video is finished playing in win8 javascript/html app. I am trying to make above examples work locally first but no success so far.

I appreciate your help!!!!

P.S: There are few related questions (example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844668/controlling-an-iframe-youtube-player-within-a-windows-8-metro-js-app)  on stackoverflow but I was not able to find answer. Also I was not able to comment due to my low reputation :).

**EDIT:** Here is the actual [**HTML**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) that I am using locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @arttronics -  thanks for reply. Instead of posting code here I pointed to link. Please check out sample html page example here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started 
I copied same code in local html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 2 of the [**Google Sample YouTube Page**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) you provided, change this:

```
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

to this:

```
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

Then, this page will work locally. Also, note that you can use `https` as well.

Comment: thank you @arttronics !! it worked locally! Still doesnt work with Windows 8 app. I looked more and found out that there are many restrictions for web context. more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx

seems like my options are
1. run youtube player in ieframe in web context. somehow create a communication channel between web and local context.
2. download youtube javascripts and add to project and run everything in local context. I dont know which js files to download for YT player and how to download though. thanks again!